# Dropdown menu too narrow and not aligned

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, alignment

http://freedom-project-west-cumbria.org.uk/

I have created the above site and somewhere along the way have messed up the width of the drop down menu so that it only shows as a few px wide!  It also does not appear directly under the menu it represents.

I have tried and failed for hours on end to undo this using the wordpress css editor but it does not seem to let me edit the dropdown as it is impossible to highlight the dropdown due to it not being aligned with the main menu item.

Please could someone tell me what part of the css I need to alter and where I would find it or alternatively what other information I need to edit.

Comment: `.navigation-main ul ul a { width: 12px; ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, right click on the menu and click "inspect", assuming you have your dev tools switched on. On the styles tab you'll see :hov where you can set the state of the li item to hover, then the dropdown menu is displayed.

If you do this and then inspect the dropdown you'll see that the CSS property         `.navigation-main ul ul a {width:12px;}` is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must add style below to fix it a little bit.

```
   ul.menu li a {width:100%;)
   ul ul {width:200px;}
```

Comment: Great,  Thank you.  This means the menus can at least be used now but... how do I get the start of the drop down menu to line up with the start of the menu header eg the headings under ABOUT US line up with the start of the A of ABOUT? etc

Comment: `.navigation-main ul ul` is positioned absolute, then you can opearte it by `left` attribute. In this case is somethig about `70px`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.  90 seemed to sort it.